# Define a dataclass in a doctest body

Tags: python, python-dataclasses, doctest

I need to define a temporary dataclass in order to test a given function via [Doctest](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/doctest.html).
However, I am not able to use to [`@dataclass` decorator syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#dataclasses.dataclass) in a doctest body.

Sample file `test.py`:

```py
from typing import Any

def myprint(x: Any):
    """
    >>> from dataclasses import dataclass
    >>> @dataclass
    >>> class SomeDataClass:
    ...    field1: int
    ...    field2: str
    >>> myprint(SomeDataClass(1, "txt"))
    SomeDataClass(field1=1, field2='txt')

    """
    print(x)
```

The doctest invocation is done, as usual, with:

```
python -m doctest test.py
```

This results in a "unexpected EOF while parsing" error.

What am I doing wrong?

```
**********************************************************************
File "test.py", line 6, in test.myprint
Failed example:
    @dataclass
Exception raised:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/lib/python3.9/doctest.py", line 1336, in __run
        exec(compile(example.source, filename, "single",
      File "<doctest test.myprint[1]>", line 1
        @dataclass
                  ^
    SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
**********************************************************************
[ this error is triggered by the first one and is not relevant ]
File "test.py", line 10, in test.myprint
Failed example:
    myprint(SomeDataClass(1, "txt"))
Exception raised:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/lib/python3.9/doctest.py", line 1336, in __run
        exec(compile(example.source, filename, "single",
      File "<doctest test.myprint[3]>", line 1, in <module>
        myprint(SomeDataClass(1, "txt"))
    TypeError: SomeDataClass() takes no arguments
**********************************************************************
1 items had failures:
   2 of   4 in test.myprint
***Test Failed*** 2 failures.
```

This test was done on Python 3.9.

Comment: Did you look at how this works in an actual REPL session?

Comment: `myprint` is irrelevant to the problem. You could reproduce the same issue with just `print()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A decorator isn't a statement on its own; it connects with the definition below (`class` or `def`). So replace the `>>> class` with `... class`.